# Where is the Google Chrome crash dump location for Mac?

Tags: mac, google-chrome

For Windows, [here](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=107788) are the instructions.

Where are the crash logs on Mac OS X?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the Mac, Chrome’s [crash dumps](http://www.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines/reporting-crash-bug#TOC-Mac) are located in

```
~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Crash Reports
```

To find the folder in OS X Lion activate Finder, then press <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> and paste the path from above.

Comment: Alt and GO[toolbar] ?

Comment: are you able to find the location

Comment: As of Chrome 80 on macOS Catalina 10.15.3, the location is: `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Crashpad`

Comment: @tony19 How to open them?

Answer (score 0):

The location is now:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Crashpad
```

(usually in the `/completed` subfolder)

Unfortunately, there's not much you can easily glean from these .dmp files.
Here's Google's documentation:

https://www.chromium.org/developers/decoding-crash-dumps/
https://www.chromium.org/developers/crash-reports/#TOC-Working-with-Minidumps

Most of those instructions assume you are either building Chrome from source (so you have "symbols" files available to decode the .dmp file) *or* you are a Google employee (so you have access to an internal server that does the decoding automatically for any official Chrome release).

From the second link though, it sounds like you can get a *small* amount of info by either:

- Download the [Crashpad](https://crashpad.chromium.org/) tool and then run `minidump_stackwalk -m` on it; or
- Install WinDBG on a *Windows* machine, and open the .dmp file there. "As long as the CPU architecture is supported by Windows, the debugger will be able to understand the exception record and disassemble the code around the exception, show call stacks (without symbols though), and let you inspect the contents of the stack and registers."